# GitLab deploy token fails on EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 AMI, and nowhere else

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab, ubuntu-18.04

GitLab container registry deploy tokens do not appear to work on the most recent official Ubuntu 18.04 x86 AMI (`ami-085925f297f89fce1`) running on an EC2 instance, but they do work in other Ubuntu 18.04 environments, and on other AMIs with the same security group settings. I tried multiple tokens and multiple instances to try to rule out user error.

I am wondering if this problem reproduces for others, and, if so, what could be causing it. The most likely explanation is a bug, but it could also be some security feature of Ubuntu that I do not understand. The error goes like this:

```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install -y docker.io
> docker login -u <the_username> -p <the_token> registry.gitlab.com

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Here are some situations where deploy tokens worked fine:

- On my Mac, which is running Docker 19.03.8
- On an Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container running inside said Mac
- On an Amazon Linux EC2 instance of the same type, running in the same subnet with the same security groups

In the Ubuntu and Amazon Linux environments, the Docker version was 19.03.6.

To completely rule out security group issues, I briefly tried a wide-open security group (all ports open for ingress and egress for CIDR `0.0.0.0/0`) for the Ubuntu EC2 instance. It had no effect.

In each case (except the Mac terminal), these were totally clean slates: the only things I did were update the OS (`sudo apt update` or `sudo yum update`, install Docker, and then attempt to authenticate with `docker login -u <the_username> -p <the_token> registry.gitlab.com`.

In every case but the Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance, I quickly got `Login Succeeded`. For the Ubuntu EC2 instance, however, I got the above error.

Does it reproduce for others? What might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as it so often is, is `sudo`.

On Linux, you need to use `sudo` with `docker login`, because it writes your credentials to a plaintext system file. Presumably, you don't need `sudo` on the Mac because Docker Desktop does something smarter than store the credentials in plaintext.

On Amazon Linux, you can authenticate without sudo, but it doesn't stick: when you go to pull a private repo, you get `access denied` as if you'd never logged in. On Ubuntu, it just aborts with a cryptic error. Arguably, the latter is better, but both outcomes leave something to be desired.

Why did it work on the Ubuntu container running inside MacOS? Because when you run `docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash`, you are plunked into a root shell. Everything you do is `sudo`.